# Import tensorflow error

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, tensorflow

I installed **tensorflow** using anaconda distribution and I am unable to use the same in python.

When I import tensorflow using `import tensorflow` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/kaxilnaik/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Users/kaxilnaik/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/Users/kaxilnaik/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import attr_value_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_attr__value__pb2
  File "/Users/kaxilnaik/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/attr_value_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__pb2
  File "/Users/kaxilnaik/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_shape_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__shape__pb2
  File "/Users/kaxilnaik/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape_pb2.py", line 22, in <module>
    serialized_pb=_b('\n,tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.proto\x12\ntensorflow\"z\n\x10TensorShapeProto\x12-\n\x03\x64im\x18\x02 \x03(\x0b\x32 .tensorflow.TensorShapeProto.Dim\x12\x14\n\x0cunknown_rank\x18\x03 \x01(\x08\x1a!\n\x03\x44im\x12\x0c\n\x04size\x18\x01 \x01(\x03\x12\x0c\n\x04name\x18\x02 \x01(\tB2\n\x18org.tensorflow.frameworkB\x11TensorShapeProtosP\x01\xf8\x01\x01\x62\x06proto3')
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'syntax'
```

I tried reinstalling anaconda as well as uninstalling `protobuf` which I found as an answer somewhere in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should uninstall tensorflow as well, and make sure protobuf is uninstalled.  You can try `brew uninstall protobuf` as well.  Then reinstall protobuf, and tensorflow.  Tensorflow requires protobuf version 3.x

```
pip install 'protobuf>=3.0.0a3'
```

You can test your protobuf version:

```
import google.protobuf
>>> print google.protobuf.__version__
```

Comment: I already have the latest protobuf.

     `protobuf 3.0.0b2`

Also I have uninstalled & reinstalled tensorflow & protobuf. But still the same error

Comment: Did you print your protobuf version? It could be reading from incorrectly set PATH.  If it is correct, there is some other installation problem.